# Orange 2.7's equivalent "test_on_data" in Orange 3

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, orange

I read the documentation for Orange 2.7 which has

```
 test_on_data(classifiers, examples, store_classifiers=False, store_examples=False)

 #Test classifiers on the given data
```

It seems that by using this functionality, I am able to use a saved model and test on a test data.
However, I did not find the similar functionality in Orange 3 which only has

```
class Orange.evaluation.testing.TestOnTestData(train_data, test_data, learners, store_data=False, store_models=False, preprocessor=None, callback=None, n_jobs=1)
```

But if I use this function, it seems I have to provide the input file.
Does anyone know what is the equivalent function of "test_on_data" in Orange 3 or I have to downgrade orange 3 to 2.7 in order to use this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `test_on_data` in Orange 3 .